# Render tracking pixel in HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email

Which one of these 3 options is most suitable for adding a 1x1 tracking pixel (aka web bug or web beacon) to **HTML email**:

1. `<img src="TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden">`
2. `<img src="TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE" style="display:none">`
3. `<img src="TRACKING-PIXEL-URL-GOES-HERE" width="0" height="0">`
4. Other?

The image itself is a transparent 1x1 GIF.

Please note this is not for a web page, this is for **HTML email** with its ill-defined CSS support.

Comment: Why not combine all three? Although I imagine the the "transparent" part would be sufficient if the image was downloaded at all.

Comment: 1×1? Who’s going to notice either way? Also note that this is exactly why images are blocked in most mail clients by default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest just using a transparent image and a normal image tag - This is how Litmus does it:

```
<img src="..." width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

This is how Campaign Monitor does it:

```
<img src="..." style="height:1px !important; width:1px !important; border: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important" width="1" height="1" border="0">
```

Two very trusted sources, so either of those 2 options would definitely suffice.

Comment: I know this isn't strictly the question but I was wondering how to track that image distinctly?

Comment: @SeanH The image is just a mechanism to hit a 3rd party URL triggered on email page load. I don't think it even needs to be an image link in the email, although ISPs may block it if it doesn't return an image. One way is to point it to a webpage with analytics (use merge tags/URL params in the URL to pass through more identifiable data to analytics). On the receiving webpage, return the page headers as an image, which basically returns the image even though it was actually a webpage and additional scripts were run first. I've used PHP to create dynamic image scripts like this in the past.